# Jhipster returns org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I'm using JHipster in a microservice architecture (registry, gateway, uaa server). I extended the default jhipster user inside my uaa server with a profile entity (using the @mapsId annotation and a one-to-one relationship according to this article: https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/022_tip_registering_user_with_additional_information.html).

My problem is the following: if I register a new user in the jhipster gateway my profile is created and written to the database with a shared id between the user and profile, everything works fine. Now, if I want to delete the profile entity, the user entity should be deleted too (because no user without a profile) but I get the following exception:

`org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1`

If I delete the user entity, my profile gets deleted too, so the cascading should work.

**User Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jhi_user")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class User extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
...

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Profile profile;
```

**Profile Entity**

```
@Entity(name = "Profile")
@Table(name = "profile")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Profile implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;
...
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @MapsId
    private User user;
```

**Foreignkey constraint for the profile table using liquibase:**

```
<addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="id"
                                 baseTableName="profile"
                                 constraintName="fk_profile_user_id"
                                 referencedColumnNames="id"
                                 referencedTableName="jhi_user"
                                 onDelete="CASCADE"
                                 />
```

Do I miss something here? I also tried using the hibernate annotations instead of the JPA ones, but didn't change anything, so I'm thinking this might be a problem with Hibernate itself.

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. You request information in such a way that if zero or more than one results are found, an error is thrown, and no results are found

Comment: I understand what this message is telling me. My problem is that i dont know how i can resolve it. If i look at my logs i can see that jhipster deletes my user entries first, and then my profile (which returns null, because user and profile share their id), so i guess i need to tell hibernate to delete my profile entity first?

Comment: Have you tried to set cascading only on one side of the relation? Basically, it seems to me that the User owns the profile and so should take care of the cascading, not the reverse.

Comment: yeah already tried that. cascading on both sides was just because i had no other idea what to do. Jhipster states that the other entity (not the user) should own the relation, which i thought it would. so maybe this causes my problem

Comment: quick update. i removed the cascading from the profile entity, and tried deleting again. my logs tell me, that the profile with the corresponding id are deleted, but both the profile and the user are still in the database.

Comment: @xBoLLo Could you try to remove `@Cache` annotation from the both entities and recheck your problem.

Comment: Have you enabled Hibernate detailed logging?

Comment: @SternK tried that, but its still the same error. I also checked the relationship again, but i did everything according to the jhipster documentation. the problem is still the order which the entities are deleted, but i dont know how/where to change this.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou this is my log: Hibernate: 
  `  delete 
    from
        jhi_user_authority 
    where
        user_id=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        jhi_user 
    where
        id=?
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        profile 
    where 
        id=?`  like i said. the deletion order is messed up. if i delete the user first, my profile entry doen't have an id, which leads to the exception. i also tried using orphanRemoval = true, which didnt work either

Comment: @xBoLLo How you tried to delete entity, via `EntityManager.remove`?

Comment: @SternK I'm using a profileRepository (CrudRepository) for this, which is generated by Jhipster. `profileRepository.deleteById(id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by adding a new "user_id" column to my profile table. I added a foreign key constraint to the id column (user table) and my user_id column (profile table). not exactly what i wanted, but it works. Just make sure, to enable cascading on both sides of the relationship, so profiles are automatically deleted when you delete it's user.